Swift 6 - How to use Typed Throws inside a Task
I am trying to use typed throws from an async function but the compiler can't seem to infer the type. I get the error Type '_ErrorCodeProtocol' has no member 'one'
if I do the same code not async it works. What am I doing wrong?
enum MyError: Error {
    case one
}

struct MyTest {

    func test() async throws(MyError) {}
    
    func anotherTest() {
        Task {
            do {
                try await test()
            } catch {
                switch error {
                case .one:
                    print("one")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Task has a generic, Failure, which is defined as an existential any Error, which appears to interfere with the typed throwing inference logic. (Interesting, Xcode’s “Quick help” seems to understand that error is MyError, but the compiler does not.)
You can get around this if you explicitly specify that the do block throws(MyError):
func foo() {
    Task {
        do throws(MyError) {
            try await test()
        } catch {
            switch error {
            case .one: print("one")
            }
        }
    }
}

This is a bit clumsy, but gets around your immediate problem.
Probably needless to say, this explicit typing of the do-catch block is not needed if you are just writing an async function, but only appears to be necessary when embedding this in a closure, such as when introducing unstructured concurrency with the Task initializer.

The other alternative to do throws(…)-catch is do-catch let error as …:
func bar() {
    Task {
        do {
            try await funcWithTypedThrow()
        } catch let error as MyError {
            switch error {
            case .one: print("one")
            }
        }
    }
}

It is a subtle point, but this is not quite the same thing as do throws(…)-catch. In Xcode 16 and Swift 6, this catch let error as MyError in bar is (incorrectly) understood to have uncaught errors, and will make this a throwing Task. You won't notice this unless you save the Task to a property or ivar for our cancelation handling, but it is something to note.

"which is defined as just conforming to Error" The problem is that it is not defined as conforming to Error, it is defined (for the Task initializer) as being Error. See my related answer linked in my comment on the question.

Your point is taken and I’ve clarified my answer to note that it is explicitly an existential any Error. My point here is that do-catch let error as MyError pattern is that the resulting Task is a Task<Void, any Error>, whereas using do throws(MyError)-catch correctly produces a Task<Void, Never>.

I think my remaining question would be whether we agree with the OP that there's kind of a hole in the language here with regard to Task.

As I’ve been playing around with it, I’ve walked away with a panoply of problems related to typed-throws. The inferred throw-types for Task is but one example. The inference with closures is also a tad awkward. There are bugs regarding exhaustiveness of catch statements, too. There is another issue where  the caught error is recognized as the custom type, but the switch cases do not. There are lots of tiny problems here.

All of that having been said, SE-0413 explicitly acknowledges that the “full type inference” didn’t make it into Swift 6.0, so I cut them a little slack. What we’ve got here is better than nothing, but also a tad incomplete and suffers some minor bugs (which we can largely work around, for now).

@matt I would put it a little differently:
The fact that the generic Task implementation from the Swift stdlib only supports Never and any Error type parameters conflicts with the Swift 6 typed throws.
I.e. in this specific case it's more of a stdlib issue. The following line demonstrates the core issue of Task: let work = Task<Void, MyError> { try await test() } resulting in the compiler error Referencing initializer 'init(priority:operation:)' on 'Task' requires the types 'MyError' and 'any Error' be equivalent

It looks like the problem with Task is two-fold. First the operation parameter for the throwing Task initializer is defined as throws and it should be throws(Failure). Second, this is defined within an extension with a where Failure == any Error qualifier (which, as an aside, is a curious constraint to add given that Failure is already defined as where Failure: Error in the top level definition). In my own types, if made those two changes, typed-throws worked as expected.

The issue doesn't seem to be related to Tasks, but with closures.
The following code has the same issue.
        let closure = {
            do {
                try await test()
            } catch {

                switch error {

                case .one:
                    print("one")
                }
            }
        }

Another (stil not nice) workaround seems to be to use a func instead
    func anotherTest() {
        func taskOperation() async {
            do {
                try await test()
            } catch {

                switch error {

                case .one:
                    print("one")
                }
            }
        }

        Task(operation: taskOperation)
    }


The difference with closures is that a closure can be defined as throwing a particular type of Error, e.g., let closure: () async throws(MyError) -> Void = { try await test() }. See https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/feaa23876da000e681d41b81031fb33b. This stands in contrast to Task, where the typed-throw error type cannot be specified.
